# Mascara e validador de CPF e CNPJ - Erro

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Olá, achei um site onde faz a marcara e validação do CPF e CNPJ [Link](https://github.com/gmgomess/jQuery-CPF-CNPJ-Validator-plugin).

Estou testando, mas parece que não funciona. Estou fazendo errado ou tem algum problema no código original?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.validate').cpfcnpj({
    mask: true,
    validate: 'cpfcnpj',
    event: 'click',
    //validateOnlyFocus: true,
    handler: '.btn',
    ifValid: function(input) {
      input.removeClass("error");
      alert(returnType);
    },
    ifInvalid: function(input) {
      input.addClass("error");
      alert(returnType);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.error {
  border-color: #F70202
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/gmgomess/jQuery-CPF-CNPJ-Validator-plugin/blob/master/jquery.cpfcnpj.js"></script>


<input type="text" class="validate" />
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Test" />
```

Comment: Funciona sim, você precisa baixar o javascript para sua máquina e utilizar localmente, vai rodar tranquilamente, pelo endereço não funciona.

Answer (score 2):

Você está tentando carregar o script pelo endereço do repositório do GitHub:

```
<script src="https://github.com/gmgomess/jQuery-CPF-CNPJ-Validator-plugin/blob/master/jquery.cpfcnpj.js"></script>
```

Você precisa do arquivo junto ao seu projeto (lado-a-lado) ou subir em algum servidor.

> Por: [Virgilio Novic](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/54880/virgilio-novic)